# Java - How to move specific integers at start of the list?

Tags: java, list, sorting

I am searching for an easy way to reorder specific elements in a list of integers in Java.

For an example, I have a list containing elements:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,2,2,2,3,3,6,6,6,...
```

I need to always have all '6' as the starting elements then all '7' then all '3' then the other integers ordered or not. So the expected result would be:

```
6,6,6,7,3,3,3,0,1,2,4,5,8,9,10,0,2,2,2,...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for. Could you edit your question with the expected result?

Comment: Provide a custom comparator and do whatever you want to do.

Comment: customized Comparator may be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generic comparator for this case:

```
class CustomSorting<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    private List<T> orderList;

    public CustomSorting(T ... elements) {
        this.orderList = Arrays.asList(elements);
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T a, T b) {
        return weight(a) - weight(b);
    }

    private int weight(T a) {
        int index = orderList.indexOf(a);
        return index >= 0 ? index : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,2,2,2,3,3,6,6,6);

    System.out.println(list);
    Collections.sort(list, new CustomSorting<>(6,7,3));
    System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 0, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6]
[6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 3, 3, 3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 0, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the items in a list already (and not as a String, as it looks like in your question), you can define your own Comparator to sort the list:

```
class Sort {
    public static int strangeCompare(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        return valueOf(i2) - valueOf(i1);
    }
    private static int valueOf(Integer i) {
        switch (i.intValue()) {
        case 6: return 10;
        case 7: return 7;
        case 3: return 3;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

And then sort your list by

```
List<Integer> yourList = //...
Collections.sort(yourList, Sort::strangeCompare);
```

Comment: @RobinTopper I think the `return`s will do just fine ;)

Comment: Don't need any break, since all statements have a return. Adding a break after it, will give you a error pointing a "dead code"